# Angular2 filter table based on two inputs using custom pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I have a table in which two columns are dates represented as strings. I want to filter the table based on two inputs (which are populated by two ngb-datepickers, default value is null). Using a custom pipe I am currently getting console error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` as well as my table not rendering to the page, none of the buttons work, and form validation doesn't work. I import my custom pipe into declarations in app.module.ts. Minimal code is included to show entire scope, let me know if anything is confusing or to include more.

mainpage.component.html:

```
<div>
  <label>Start Date:</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="startDateValue">
</div>
  <label>End Date:</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="endDateValue">
</div>
//'let idx=index' and 'let even=even' are used to change color of the rows but I took out that code. The 'onClick' function just takes the row and uses an EventEmitter to output it.
<tr *ngFor="let dPoint of theData | searchDates:startDateValue:endDateValue; let idx=index; let even=even;" (click)="onClick(dPoint, idx)">
  <td>{{dPoint.tDataPoint}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tICCP}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tStartDate}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tEndDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

mainpage.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-page',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'mainpage.component.html',
  providers: [DataTableService, DatePipe]
})

export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {
  secondForm : FormGroup;
  theData:DataTable[] = [];

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe, private dataService: DataTableService, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){
    this.secondForm = fb.group({
      'startDate' : [null, Validators.required],
      'endDate' : [null, Validators.required]
    }, {validator: this.endDateAfterOrEqualValidator})
  }

  getTable(): void {
    this.dataService.getTable().then(theData => this.theData = theData);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

search-pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "searchDates"
})

//if I comment out the code inside the transform function, I get no console errors, all functionality previously mentioned that stopped working now does again, but my entire table still does not render
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args?){
    let firstDate = new Date(args[0]);
    let secondDate = new Date(args[1]);
    //let [minDate, maxDate] = args;
    return value.filter(row => {
      return row.tStartDate >= firstDate && row.tEndDate <= secondDate;
    });
  }
}
```

I believe my issues are improper syntax/functionality in my transform function. I've seen similar issues [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201684/angular2-pipe-not-working?rq=1) but I can't seem to format it for my needs and am just too unfamiliar with Angular2, especially pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arg is not an array , is just the first thing after :

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, firstDate , secondDate , arg3 , arg4 ){

    return value.filter(row => {
      return row.tStartDate >= firstDate && row.tEndDate <= secondDate;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help in your example as it was solution for my problem.

Try to reuse `async` buikd-in pipe to notify Angular to proceed form building only after promise resolving.

Your example may looks like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dPoint of theData | async | searchDates:startDateValue:endDateValue; let idx=index; let even=even;" (click)="onClick(dPoint, idx)">
  <td>{{dPoint.tDataPoint}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tICCP}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tStartDate}}</td>
  <td>{{dPoint.tEndDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

But first you need to change your `theData` type - you need promise as return type

```
var theData: Promise<DataTable> = null;
this.theData = this.dataService.getTable();
```

So using this approach your repeater do not start proceessing your data until your promise will not be resolved. On this stage you will have your data and your `searchDates` pipe will not cause empty-data-exception.

Here is more details about this pipe https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html